# Is there any difference between "throw someone" and "throw someone off" in the sense of confusing?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there is any difference  between *throw someone* and *throw someone off* in the sense of confusing? For example:

> The interviewer's question **threw** me. I didn't know how to answer it.
>
> The interviewer's question **threw** me **off**. I didn't know how to answer it.

Comment: No significant difference really. There's also "threw me for a loop."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously in OP's *exact* context there's no scope for any difference in meaning depending on whether (optional) preposition ***off*** is included or not.

But in other contexts, ***to throw someone off*** is often "short for" ***...off the scent*** - it means to ***mislead, deceive*** someone who's trying to find something out. Whereas the prepositionless version normally just mean ***to confuse, destabilise, disorient*** (someone who wasn't necessarily seeking anything anyway).

---

Note that with or without the preposition, this question concerns the ***metaphorical*** usage. But there's also the ***literal*** sense - again, with ***off*** being entirely optional...

> *The badly-trained horse **threw** the rider [**off**]*

...where we can safely ignore the idea of the horse *misleading* the rider - so as with OP's example, there's only one possible interpretation (the rider was literally "bucked" right out of his saddle, and thrown to the ground).

Answer (score 2):

> 1. The interviewer's question threw me. I didn't know how to answer it.
> 2. The interviewer's question threw me off. I didn't know how to answer it.

The first sentence is ambiguous:

> It threw me **for a loop**.    (I was astonished.)
>
> It threw me **off**.  (I had not expected that question.  It became difficult for me to continue my argument).

Both of the example sentences are idiomatic.  The first sentence is ambiguous because it is elliptical.